# WP_Query stock status filter Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this WP_Query code that shows me results if the value of `_pre_orders_enabled` does not exist or has the value `no`

What I want is that I also filter it by `_stock_status` I tried this but it didn't work.

My code:

```
$products = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'starts_with' => $letra,
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_pre_orders_enabled',
            'value'   => 'no',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_pre_orders_enabled',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

I tried to filter by

```
array(
    'key'     => '_stock_status',
    'value'   => 'instock',
    'compare' => '=',
),
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```php
$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'starts_with'    => $letra,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'instock',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => '_pre_orders_enabled',
                'value'   => 'no',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => '_pre_orders_enabled',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try following code.

$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'starts_with'    => $letra,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', 
        array(
            'key'     => '_pre_orders_enabled',
            'value'   => 'no',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'instock',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
) );
```